# Designing an API for a Forum

Tags: api, swagger, backend, openapi

So I am trying to figure out how to design my backend for a forum website I am building (similar to reddit) and I just want to be sure I am doing things right.

The home page will have a list of threads. Each thread listed on the home page will have the title of the thread, the number of comments, and the username of the author.

Then when you click on one of the threads it will open up that thread's page and display the title, description, author's username, number of comments, and comments.

Here is what I am thinking for a design:

### models:

**User**

```
username: string
id: number
```

**Comment**

```
id: number
author: User
dateCreated: date
content: text
replies: [Comment]
numberOfReplies: number
```

**Thread**

```
id: number
author: User
dateCreated: date
title: text
description: text
comments: [Comment]
numberOfComments: number
```

I think I will have an endpoint for grabbing a list of the threads on the main page like so:

```
GET /home/threads?pageNumber={page number}&threadsPerPage={number of threads per page}
```

The endpoint will return a list of the most recent threads based on page number and number of threads per page. Each thread returned will not have the comments since that would take too long and it's not needed for the home page. So the value for the comments variable of each thread will just be an empty array.

Then when you click on one of the threads, we will an endpoint like so:

```
GET /thread/{threadID}/comments?startIndex={start index}&count={number of comments to return}
```

This endpoint will return up to `count` comments on the thread starting from index `startIndex`. If there are more than the number of comments returned, the frontend will display a clickable text: `X more comments` at the bottom. If they click, it will hit this same endpoint to grab more comments.

If a comment has replies, the frontend will have a clickable text: `X more replies`. If the user clicks, it will hit this endpoint:

```
GET /comment/{commentID}/replies?startIndex={start index}&count={number of replies to return}
```

It will return `count` amount of comments' replies at `startindex`.

Does this seem right? I've never really built an API before so I would appreciate the advice.

Comment: It's mostly correct. The `/home/threads` can be `/threads` because you don't model home page as a resource and there is no other thing under `/home`. And usually the plural form of naming is used for collection resources, e.g. `/threads/{id}`, `/comments/{id}` .

Comment: @aleung Thanks a bunch. For posting a comment on a thread, should it be: `POST /threads/{threadID}/comments` or `POST /comments`?

Comment: Both can work. You need to think of how to distinguish if it's posting a comment reply to thread post or comment reply to a comment.